# I am not familiar with this type of printf() statement . Why my output look like this ? thanks

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>       
     int main()
     {
          int i=43;
          printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%d",i))));
          return 0;            
     }
```

what the use of nested `printf()`? I used value 43 but how other values 
 showing in output?

**Output:**

> 43211

Comment: The return value of `printf` is the number of printed characters. The usage of such nested calls of `printf` is just for demonstration purposes or for fun. There is no real benefit of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this as a simpler version of your code:

```
int main(){
    int i = 43;
    int a = printf("%d", i);
    int b = printf("%d", a);
    int c = printf("%d", b);
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

It's clear why `43` is printed. As for the other digits, they are the return value of `printf`:

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

So, what you should have been getting (considering this was your exact code) is: `43211`

- 43 is the first print
- 2 is the number of digits printed before (`'4'` + `'3'`)
- 1 is the number of digits printed before (`'2'`)
- 1 is the number of digits printed before (`'1'`)

Answer (score 3):

The return value of printf is the number of printed characters.

Let's analyze what's going on.

```
printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%d",i))));
```

The innermost `printf("%d",i)` prints obviously`43` as `i` is 43.

The next outer `printf("%d",printf("%d",i))` prints `2` because the length of the output of the previous printf is `2` (length of "43").

So up to now the output is:

> 432

The next outer printf will print `1` because the length of the output of the previous printf is the length of `"1"` which is 1.

So up to now the output is:

> 4321

The outer printf will print `1` again because the length of the output of the previous printf is the length of `"1"` which is 1.

So the final output is:

> 43211

Answer (score 0):

You are printing return values of [printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) since the first prints correctly `43`.

`printf()` doesn't return the number of "items" output like the `scanf()` family of functions do for input. It returns the actual character count.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` return an int value, so if you concatenate printf commands, the first value is the number you want to print the others are the result of printf instruction that returns in case of success the number of printed chars (even if they are carriage return or new line so not visible).

- In your case:
- 43 the first number
- 3 the printf int result
- and so on ...